# Insert £ into a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-insert

I have got an insert statement written in C#.

```
  da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation.Text);
```

As it is inserted into my database I would like the £ symbol to be in front of it,
does anyone know if this is possible ?

Comment: What happens when you switch `donation.Text'` to `"£" + donation.Text`? That said, I would not recommend storing that symbol in your db.  Just decorate your text before you display it.

Comment: what is the datatype of `Donation` column in your table?

Comment: It is possible, in several ways. There are, however, not many valid argument why yuo would do it. Could you eleborate on why you want such a thing in your database?

Comment: @Sudhakar ive set the table to a double.

Comment: Then you won't be able to store the `£` in that column anyway.

Comment: @oerkelens I am building a web app that will output a full list of all donations in the database, I need to have the donations displayed in £00.00 including a total, also the user can input donation in euro's that i will need to convert into pounds... but that is the next step.

Comment: @Abe Miessler so its best to have is as a VarChar and convert to double ?

Comment: No, store it as a double without the symbol.  When you to render the value on the page, place the `£` in front of it.

Comment: You say "display" in pounds. Your database is not for display purposes but for saving data. Just add the sign when _displaying_ the data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to display the symbol `£` for only representing `amount` you can retrieve the amount value from database and append symbol `£` as below:

Try This:

```
TextBox1.Text="£"+amount;//amount will have the value from database.
```

Sample Output:

```
£12.00
```

Comment: Problem is I display the data like. `protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer", cs);
            cs.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dgl = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dg.DataSource =dgl;
            dg.DataBind();
            cs.Close();
        }`

Comment: Okay so you are binding data to the GridView Right?